# How to run bcp utility from root drive?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, path, bcp

Machine does not have full sql server installed. but following distributable packages are installed on my machine:-

1. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities
2. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Native Client

I have a batch file that runs bcp utility. If i run this batch file from the folder where bcp.exe is sitting (...tools\binn) it works.

but my dump question is if there is any way i can run this bcp utility from c:\ drive only. Right now if it run from c:\ drive it says:-

> bcp is not recognized as an internal or external command,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the directory (...tools\binn) to your PATH variable or use the full path of the bcp executable this will work.

To add a directory to your PATH Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.
Then find the Path Variable under system variables and add your bcp directory to the list (seperated by ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the `bcp.exe` from the other **SQL Server**  or from respective **SQL Server**  path 
and copy it to batch file path, where you have your script.

While running the batch script, also please run from the same path in command line.

Comment: If you think this solves the problem, then add reasons why this solution would work, maybe quotes from help files or other sources.